# Understanding complex $.extend in modal.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was just going through some code in modal.js and came across the following line of code:

```
 var options = $.extend({}, Modal.DEFAULTS, $this.data(), typeof option == 'object' && option)
```

The line mostly makes sense, except the last part, i.e.:

```
typeof option == 'object' && option
```

I understand the `typeof` operator but I don't understand its usage in `$.extend`, can somebody explain please?

My line of difficulty can be found in the plugin code online too . [Line 296](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js#L296).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [jQuery documentation on `$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/), you'll see that it's used with the following parameters:

```
$.extend( target [, object1 ] [, objectN ] )
```

In your code:

`{}` is the target, the new object you'll be building upon.

`Modal.DEFAULTS` is an object from which you will copy the properties over to the `target`.

`$this.data()` is another object from which the properties will be added.

`typeof option == 'object' && option` is essentially saying that the properties of `option` will be copied if it is an `object`. If not, nothing will be added. This is to avoid errors if it's not defined.

It is a shorter equivalent of:

```
typeof option == 'object' ? option : false
```

Or, an even longer version:

```
(function(){ if(typeof option == 'object') {return option} return false })()
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo

**Let's go further**

If you have multiple `&&` chained, e.g.:

```
a && b && c
```

where `a`, `b` and `c` are defined variables, it will check that `a` is not falsy, if it is, return false. Otherwise it will go on to check if `b` is falsy and so on, and if all 3 conditions are truthy, it will return the last one (ie `c`). In your code, the last value is `option`.

#### JS Fiddle Demo

As [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444991/matt) mentioned it in the comments, this behavior is due to [*short circuit evaluation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation).

Comment: FWIW, the behaviour whereby JavaScript returns the first falsy value, or the last value, when evaluating `&&` chains, is due to [*short circuit evaluation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation). Also, Bootstrap's source code is full of horrendously terse idioms like this, and is overall not a great example of JavaScript code; there are *much* better examples out there.

Comment: @Matt thank you for that link which provides more info on that behavior. I knew it worked that way, but not really why.